# Does NSDictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys handles NULL/nil objects and other than NSString objects

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I am trying to initialize NSDictionary but it gives me following error:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

Here is my problematic code[Quiz.m]:

```
@implementation Quiz

@synthesize question;
@synthesize correctAnswer;
@synthesize userAnswer;
@synthesize questionId;

-(NSString*) getAsJsonString
{   
    // Following line gives the error
    NSDictionary *qDictionary=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:question,@"questionText",questionId,@"questionId",userAnswer,@"userAnswer",correctAnswer,@"correctAnswer",nil];

    ..............
    .........
    ............
    return jsonString;
}
@end
```

And here is Quiz.h file for reference

```
@interface Quiz : NSObject {

@public
    NSString * question;
    BOOL correctAnswer;
    BOOL userAnswer;
    NSInteger questionId;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString * question;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger questionId;
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL correctAnswer;
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL userAnswer;

- (NSString*) getAsJsonString;
@end
```

How should I fix it, please help me, I am new to objective c and it is driving me nuts. Does the NSDictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys handle objects other than string and null objects?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`NSDictionary` cannot store scalar values (like BOOL, NSInteger, etc.), it can store only objects. You must wrap your scalar values into `NSNumber` to store them:

```
NSDictionary *qDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]
    initWithObjectsAndKeys:question,@"questionText",
                           [NSNumber numberWithInteger:questionId],@"questionId",
                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:userAnswer],@"userAnswer",
                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:correctAnswer],@"correctAnswer",
                           nil];
```

Comment: But I am facing another problem now, when I do: 'userAnswer=[NSNull null]' it always has value YES? How can I initialize Bool with Null value?

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped. Boolean variables can't be `NULL`, they're either `YES` (non-zero) or `NO` (`0 = NULL == NO`). You have `userAnswer = [NSNull null] == YES` since `[NSNull null]` is an object, and you set `userAnswer` with the pointer to this object, and the pointer itself is not zero, so it's `YES`. Don't confuse objects with scalar values.

Comment: One final question, is there any work around for storing null value in BOOL?

Comment: One option is to have another BOOL variable with the state of your variable, something like `userAnswerWasSet`.